# Swift - [NSObject : AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Tags: ios, swift

I got this error message

```
[NSObject : AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

My code

```
self.client.getAccessToken(code, success: { (accessTokenData:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> Void in // error here
                    var accessToken = accessTokenData["access_token"]
                    self.requestMeWithToken(accessToken)
                    }, failure: { (error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    println("Quering accessToken failed \(error)")
                })
```

Comment: Which line creates the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, you should change `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` to `[NSObject : AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely omit the type specification in your success completion. You might want something like this:

```
self.client.getAccessToken(code, success: { (accessTokenData) -> Void in // error here
    if let dict = accessTokenData as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        let accessToken = dict["access_token"]
        self.requestMeWithToken(accessToken)
    }
}, failure: { (error:NSError!) -> Void in
    println("Quering accessToken failed \(error)")
})
```

This will only work if the accessTokenData can successfully be cast to a [String: AnyObject] dictionary, though.